# Java Jackson CSV: Empty Header field

Tags: java, csv, jackson

I'm trying to map a large csv file to a class with jackson csv. That csv file is not normalized at all which leads to several problems.

To give you an impression, I created a representive file:

```
,B,C,D,E,F�F,G,H H,I (I)
0,AAA,20. Jan.,10,A,5,AA: AAAA,1,A�AAA
1,BBB,05-Dez-14,12,BBB,1,BB: BBBB,32,BBB
2,CCCC,28. Jun.,80,CCCC,2,CCCC: CCCC,1,CCC / CCC
```

The first row represents the header and the first column the ids. The Jackson CsvMapper fails on mapping the first column because of it's empty name.

```
CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
CsvSchema bootstrapSchema = CsvSchema.builder()
                .setColumnSeparator(',')
                .setUseHeader(true)
                .setStrictHeaders(true)
                .setSkipFirstDataRow(true)
                .addColumn("", CsvSchema.ColumnType.NUMBER)
                .addColumn("B", CsvSchema.ColumnType.STRING)
                .addColumn("C", CsvSchema.ColumnType.STRING)
                .addColumn("D", CsvSchema.ColumnType.NUMBER)
                .addColumn("E", CsvSchema.ColumnType.STRING)
                .addColumn("F�F", CsvSchema.ColumnType.NUMBER)
                .addColumn("G", CsvSchema.ColumnType.STRING)
                .addColumn("H H", CsvSchema.ColumnType.NUMBER)
                .addColumn("I (I)", CsvSchema.ColumnType.STRING)
                .build();

        //File file = new ClassPathResource(fileName).getFile();
        MappingIterator<POJO> readValues =
                mapper.reader(POJO.class).with(bootstrapSchema).readValues(file);

        while (readValues.hasNext()){
            logger.info(mapper.writeValueAsString(readValues.nextValue()));
        }
```

And the POJO Class:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"","B","C","D","E","F�F", "G","H H","I (I)"})
public class POJO {

@JsonProperty
private Integer id;

@JsonProperty("B")
private String b;

@JsonProperty("C")
private String c;

@JsonProperty("D")
private Integer d;

@JsonProperty("E")
private String e;

@JsonProperty("F�F")
private Integer f;

@JsonProperty("G")
private String g;

@JsonProperty("HH")
private Integer h;

@JsonProperty("I (I)")
private String i;
}
```

So, how to map this mess correctly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I edited the important code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `CsvMapper` like this.

```
List<Object> objList = new CsvMapper()
                       .enable(CsvParser.Feature.SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)
                       .enable(CsvParser.Feature.TRIM_SPACES)
                       .enable(CsvParser.Feature.WRAP_AS_ARRAY)
                       .enable(CsvParser.Feature.INSERT_NULLS_FOR_MISSING_COLUMNS)
                       .readerFor(Map.class)
                       .with(CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader())
                       .readValues(file)
                       .readAll();
```

Comment: Not working yet:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field ""

Comment: Still getting the same exception when trying to read values. Looks like the problem is with the annotations in my POJO:

The first column is mapped as follows:

    @JsonProperty("")
    private Integer id;

The column is mapped in the csv with an empty header, but it tries to map it as "id" and not as "".

Comment: I had the same problem. I solved it by changing my fields from private to public